# Why does my kernel's shared memory seems to be initialized to zero?

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

As was mentioned in this [Shared Memory Array Default Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478098/is-there-a-way-of-setting-default-value-for-shared-memory-array) question, shared memory is non-initialized, i.e. can contain any value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512

__global__ void scan(float *input, float *output, int len) {
    __shared__ int data[BLOCK_SIZE];

    // DEBUG
    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.x == 0)
    {
        printf("Block Number: %d\n", blockIdx.x);
        for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; ++i)
        {
            printf("DATA[%d] = %d\n", i, data[i]);
        }
    }
    
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    dim3 block(BLOCK_SIZE, 1, 1);
    dim3 grid(10, 1, 1);
    scan<<<grid,block>>>(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

But why in this code it is not true and I'm constantly getting zeroed shared memory?

```
DATA[0] = 0
DATA[1] = 0
DATA[2] = 0
DATA[3] = 0
DATA[4] = 0
DATA[5] = 0
DATA[6] = 0
...
```

I tested with **Release** and **Debug Mode**: `-O3 -arch=sm_20`, `-O3 -arch=sm_30` and `-arch=sm_30`. The result is always the same.

Comment: Did you tested it under release and debug mode? In some projects I had observe that in debug mode shared memory was initialized to 0, but not in release mode and not general in all projects. This isn't a defined behaviour as @CygnusX1 answered in your linked question. You have to initialize shared memory on your own!

Comment: If it can contain any value than it can contain zeros, no? System may still need to reinitialize memory sometimes to prevent information leaking between processes (security).

Comment: Yes, I tested. With "-arch=sm_30" and "-O3 -arch=sm_30" options, also with "-arch=sm_20". The result is the same - zeroed shared memory.

Comment: Yes, it can contain and zero too, but the strange is that no any other values in shared memory, means that it is specially zeroed.

Comment: Zero is within the subset of "any value".

Comment: If you launch more than one wave of blocks you will likely see non-zero values in the second wave. On context switch the shared memory is reset to zero.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### tl;dr: shared memory is not initialized to 0

I think your conjecture of shared memory initialized to `0` is questionable. Try the following code, which is a slight modification of yours. Here, I'm calling the kernel twice and altering the values of the `data` array. The first time the kernel is launched, the "uninitialized" values of `data` will be all `0`'s. The second time the kernel is launched, the "uninitialized" values of `data` will be all different from `0`'s.

I think this depends on the fact that shared memory is SRAM, which exhibits [data remanence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 32

__global__ void scan(float *input, float *output, int len) {

    __shared__ int data[BLOCK_SIZE];

    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.x == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; ++i)
        {
            printf("DATA[%d] = %d\n", i, data[i]);
            data[i] = i;
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    dim3 block(BLOCK_SIZE, 1, 1);
    dim3 grid(10, 1, 1);
    scan<<<grid,block>>>(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    scan<<<grid,block>>>(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right! Thanks for this good explanation, now it is clear why we should initialize shared memory manually!