# In CUDA, how do I detect that __syncthreads() was not called by all threads in the block?

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I just ran into a weird and hard to reproduce problem in CUDA which turned out to involve undefined behaviour. I wanted thread 0 to set up some value in shared memory which should be used by all the threads.

```
__shared__ bool p;
p = false;
if (threadIdx.x == 0) p = true;
__syncthreads();
assert(p);
```

Now the `assert(p);` failed seemingly at random as I shoveled the code around and commented it out to find the issue.

I had used this construction in effectively the following undefined-behaviour context:

```
#include <assert.h>

__global__ void test() {
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) __syncthreads(); // call __syncthreads in thread 0 only: this is a very bad idea
    // everything below may exhibit undefined behaviour


    // If the above __syncthreads runs only in thread 0, this will fail for all threads not in the first warp
    __shared__ bool p;
    p = false;
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) p = true;
    __syncthreads();
    assert(p);
}

int main() {
    test << <1, 32 + 1 >> > (); // nothing happens if you have only one warp, so we use one more thread
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

The earlier `__synchthreads()` only reached by one thread was of course hidden in some functions, so it was hard to find. On my setup (sm50, gtx 980), this kernels runs through (no deadlock as advertised...) and the assertion fails for all threads outside of the first warp.

---

**TL;DR**

Is there any standard way to detect `__syncthreads()` not being called by all threads in a block? Maybe some debugger setting I am missing?

I could maybe construct my own (very slow) `checked__syncthreads()` that could detect the situation using maybe atomics and global memory, but I'd rather have a standard solution.

Comment: try reading the synccheck section of the `cuda-memcheck` [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#synccheck-tool).

Answer (score 1):

You have a threaded data race condition in your original code.
Thread 0 may advance up to and execute "p=true", but after that, a *different* thread might not have progressed at all and will still be back at the p=false line, overwriting the result.

Easiest fix for this specific example would simply to have ONLY thread 0 write to p, something like

```
__shared__ bool p;
if (threadIdx.x == 0) p = true; 
__syncthreads();
assert(p);
```

Comment: I did not realize that, thank you. That now makes me wonder why I dont have a problem without the UB invoking initial synchthreads. Probably it changes the scheduling, which otherwise happens to be such that the race you mentioned does not manifest.

Comment: This isn't actually safe. For threads other than thread 0, p is uninitialized. It might be false, it might be true. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22174503/4490331